# How to start audio recorder and media player at the same time

Tags: android, audio

I am making Karokae application in Android and i am trying to sync media player and audio recorder but i am not able to do it.

If MediaPlayer started first and recording started later there is latency of 180 m/s.

If Recorder started first and wait for the read still the Media Player is started there is delay of 96 m/s

These values varies from devices. how can i fix it.

Comment: possibly duplicate [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564264/recording-audio-and-playing-audio-at-the-same-time?rq=1)

Comment: Only Native is the solution.